# Listing Directory

Tags: bash, unix

I want to write a bash to list the directory under /usr/jboss/jbosseap that content directories (app_m1 or app_m01)

I want to list either of the naming convention

This is what i'm doing currently but it doesn't work

```
ls -1d *m{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}
```

It only works if both (app_m1 and app_m01) are present.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do this, here's a simple version :

```
find . -type d -name "app_m1" -o -name "app_m01"
```

Comment: Amir, thank for ur reply, this would help, but the issue im having is the "app" part is always changing the only consistent one is "m1" or "m01". so it's like "xxxxx_m1" or "xxxx_m01" and the 1 can be [0-9] and the 01 can be [0-9][0-9]

Comment: find . -type d -name "*m01" -o -name "*m1"

Comment: This is what im using right now, and it works for me {find -type d -name "*m[0-9]" -o -name "*m[0-9][0-9]"}